# Preg replace ../../ using linux command sed and xargs

Tags: linux, bash, sed, preg-replace

Preg replace ../../ using linux command sed and xargs and replace all files in the folder and in the sub folder of the current folder

I have many files which link by this way

```
<link rel="pear-icon" sizes="100" href="../../pear.png" />
<link rel="photo-icon" sizes="100" href="../../photo.png" />
```

and many others.

I want to sed xargs replace them and remove the

```
../../
```

to make it become

```
<link rel="pear-icon" sizes="100" href="pear.png" />
<link rel="photo-icon" sizes="100" href="photo.png" />
```

How do I achieve it. Thanks for helping

Comment: `sed -r 's,([.][.]/){2},,g' file`

Comment: @Kent it is ../../ to (blank) , how do i achieve it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below regex to replace the occurrence of `../../`

```
$ sed 's/..\/..\///g' /tmp/file 
<link rel="pear-icon" sizes="100" href="pear.png" />
<link rel="pear-icon" sizes="100" href="photo.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute this:

`sed 's/\.\.\///g'`

Or

`sed 's%../%%g'`